# Mediatek 8163 TWRP 7" tablet

Tags: twrp

Does anyone know where I can find a working Mediatek 8163 TWRP for a 7-in Android tablet.

This generic Chinese tablet does not have any recovery so it is very unusual. I have made a scatter file for the partitions but I do not have the expertise to completely port a new TWRP image.

Comment: how can we port recovery if no recovery exist?

Comment: Mediatek 8163 is a CPU/chipset but your tablet has other components recovery has to include drivers for like touch screen, therefore you need a recovery that exactly matches your device not just the chipset.

Comment: There is a recovery partition however it's just a duplicate of the boot image. With regard to the brand, it's a no name generic xiol from China.  Is there not a way to take the existing drivers from the ROM and incorporate them into a recovery?

Comment: try hovatek auto porter